# gzip being added to the Content-Encoding header multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, http-headers

~(I found out when it happens, see bottom of question)

I am working with a traditional ASP.NET web application. There is an .aspx page that hosts an angular 11 application which loads fine 9/10 times but occasionally a bad response is returned with a 200 OK status. When this happens, in Firefox a page loads with a "content encoding error" and in Chrome and Edge, just a blank screen with the same verbiage in console.

Using Wireshark, I was able to determine that when the "content-encoding-error" occurs the response header has three comma separated "gzip" values appended to the **Content-Encoding** header, see below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip, gzip, gzip
...
```

Whereas, a normal response from the .aspx page look like this.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
..
```

I can duplicate the issue using one of aspx's [web method] calls:

```
 var ctx = HttpContext.Current
 var unused = ctx.Response.Filter // Because apparently you must access it before you can set it
 ctx.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(ctx.Response.OutputStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal)
 ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip") 
 ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip") // <--Gzip added twice here
```

The troubling part is that the multiple "gzip" values are on the response from the aspx page itself. I have search the entire code base and all web.config(s) in an attempt to find where this compression is being applied but to no avail. So, I am thinking it could be a third party doing this.

We use DevExtreme and I have been looking at these settings in our config:

```
<add key="DXEnableCallbackCompression" value="true" />
<add key="DXEnableResourceCompression" value="true" />
<add key="DXEnableResourceMerging" value="true" />
<add key="DXEnableHtmlCompression" value="true" />
```

I am still having trouble scanning the code for issues. Does anyone know of a trick using fiddler or Wireshark or any other tool that could reveal where these headers are sporadically showing triples at?

Edit: Here is the GET request header which returns a response which proper encoding ~90% of the time.

```
GET http://xxx/xxx.aspx?xxx=4 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36 Edg/92.0.902.73
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Referer: http://xxx/Home.aspx
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=x; .ASPXAUTH=x;
```

**Found out when it happens:**

I was able to duplicate this issue on a regular basis. If I close all browser sessions and recycle the app pool, the issue occurs on the first request. On subsequent requests, the issue does not happen.

Also, the culprit is a google script embedded on the HTML page. When this script is removed the page loads fine on first request after a recycle or not.

**Culprit Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=
<%=GoogleMapAPIKey%>&channel=<%=GoogleMappingChannel%>"></script>
```

I am sure it is not the js file itself. The keys are embedded into the tag via  server side processors. Those two processor's call an API to get the keys and those calls are gzipped. I still don't know why the aspx's response header is getting three "gzips" when the js include statement is present in the page markup.

I may remove this wall of text and add a new question due to the new findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two calls to a function that added Gzip encoding prior to page load and at that time the response was the aspx page itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to occur when you Gzip encoding was added to outgoing  that were being triggered from markup on the aspx page. All web methods that are called after page load and in an async fasion from the angular client have no encoding issue.

There were two  called via a page property that was triggered by page markup to access its value. These web methods had gzip applied and *I guess* since these were processed earlier in the page-lifecycle something was getting mixed up.

My problem was solved by removing the compression on those two calls.